# Set partitions and permanents

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, partitions, combinatorial-identities, permanent

Let $a(n)=$ Number of ordered set partitions of $[n]$ such that the smallest element of each block is odd.

```
Example:

a(3) = 3: 123, 12|3, 3|12.

a(4) = 5: 1234, 124|3, 3|124, 12|34, 34|12.
```

See [A290384](http://oeis.org/A290384) for details.

Motivated by [Question 403336](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403336/) and [Question 403386](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403386), I consider the permanents  $\operatorname{per}(A)$ where
$$A=\left[\left\lceil \frac{2j-k}{n+\cos^2(\frac{n\pi}{2})}\right\rceil \right]_{1\le j,k\le n}$$ and $\lceil \cdot\rceil$ is the ceil function.

When $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$, $A=$
$$\left[ \begin {array}{c} 1\end {array} \right] ,$$

$$\left[ \begin {array}{cc} 1&0\\ 1&1\end {array} \right], $$

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\ 1&1&1
\\ 2&2&1\end {array} \right]
,$$

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&0&0&0\\ 1&1&1&0
\\ 1&1&1&1\\ 2&2&1&1\end {array}
 \right]
,$$

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 1&0&0&0&0\\ 1&1&1&0&0
\\ 1&1&1&1&1\\ 2&2&1&1&1
\\ 2&2&2&2&1\end {array} \right]
,$$

$$\left[ \begin {array}{cccccc} 1&0&0&0&0&0\\ 1&1&1&0
&0&0\\ 1&1&1&1&1&0\\ 1&1&1&1&1&1
\\ 2&2&1&1&1&1\\ 2&2&2&2&1&1
\end {array} \right] 
$$
respectively.

Numerical computation indicates that
$$\operatorname{per}(A)=a(n)$$
for $1≤n≤21$.

```
n per(A)
1 1
2 1
3 3
4 5
5 23
6 57
7 355
8 1165
9 9135
10 37313
11 352667
12 1723605
13 19063207
14 108468169
15 1374019539
16 8920711325
17 127336119839
18 928899673425
19 14751357906571
20 119445766884325
21 2088674728868631
```

Thus, we obtain the following

**Conjecture 1.** For any positive integer $n$,$$\operatorname{per}(A) = a(n).$$

**Question 1.** Is this identity correct? How to prove it?

---

**EDIT**

Let

$$B=\left[\left\lceil \frac{j+k}{n+\cos^2(\frac{n\pi}{2})}\right\rceil \right]_{1\le j,k\le n}$$
where $\lceil \cdot\rceil$ is the ceil function.

When $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$, $B=$

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{c} 2\end {array} \right], $$

$$\left[ \begin {array}{cc} 1&1\\ 1&2\end {array}
 \right], $$

$$\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&1&2\\ 1&2&2
\\ 2&2&2\end {array} \right] ,$$

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&1&2
\\ 1&1&2&2\\ 1&2&2&2\end {array}
 \right] ,$$

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 1&1&1&1&2\\ 1&1&1&2&2
\\ 1&1&2&2&2\\ 1&2&2&2&2
\\ 2&2&2&2&2\end {array} \right] ,$$

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{cccccc} 1&1&1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&1&1
&1&2\\ 1&1&1&1&2&2\\ 1&1&1&2&2&2
\\ 1&1&2&2&2&2\\ 1&2&2&2&2&2
\end {array} \right]
$$
respectively.

We have the following

**Conjecture 2.** For any positive integer $n$,
$$\operatorname{per}(B)=\frac{3-(-1)^n}{2}F(n)$$
where $F(n)$ is the [Fubini numbers](http://oeis.org/A000670), i.e. the number of ordered partitions of $[n]$.

It is equivalent to

**Conjecture 3.** For any positive integer $n$,
$$\operatorname{per}(C)=F(n),$$
where $$C=\left[\left\lceil\frac{j+k}{n+1}\right\rceil\right]_{1\le j,k\le n}.$$

Numerical computation indicates that it is true for $1≤n≤21$.

**Question 2.** Are these new results? How to prove them?

**A2**: By @Peter Taylor's comments, Conjectures 2 and 3 are  known results.

---

**ADDED**

Today (2021-9-24), I discovered the following interesting arithmetic properties  of $a(n)$

**Conjecture 4.** For any prime  $p$,

$$a(n) \equiv a(n+p(p-1)) \pmod p.$$

Noting that $a(1)=a(2)=1$, we have

**Conjecture 5.** For any prime  $p$ ,
$$a(p^2-p+1) \equiv 1 \pmod p,$$
$$a(p^2-p+2) \equiv 1 \pmod p.$$

Numerical computation indicates that it is true for $2≤p≤19$.

Moreover

**Conjecture 6.** For any prime  $p$ and positive integer $n\geq h \geq 1$,

$$a(n) \equiv a(n+p^h(p-1)) \pmod{p^h}.$$

It is similar to [Daniel Barsky's congruence](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Eslc/opapers/s05barsky.html) for [Fubini numbers](http://oeis.org/A000670).

**Daniel Barsky's Congruence.** For any prime  $p$ and positive integer $n\geq h \geq 1$,

$$F(n) \equiv F(n+p^{h-1}(p-1)) \pmod{p^h},$$

where $F(n)$ is the [Fubini numbers](http://oeis.org/A000670).

**Question 3.** Are these congruences correct? How to prove them?

---

**ADDED** (2021-9-27)

**Claim.** Conjecture 4 is true for $2 \leq p \leq 5$.

**Proof.**  Obviously, we have $a(n)\equiv 1 \pmod{2}$.
For $3\leq p \leq 5$, we use the following generating function
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} a(n)x^n = \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\binom{-\frac1x-1}{k-1}\binom{\frac1x-1}k},$$
which is proved by Max Alekseyev.

When $p=3$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\geq 1} a(n)x^n 
&\equiv  \sum_{1 \leq k \leq 2} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\binom{-\frac1x-1}{k-1}\binom{\frac1x-1}k}\\
&=-\frac{x}{x-1}+2\,{\frac {{x}^{3}}{ \left( x+1 \right)  \left( 2\,{x}^{2}-3\,x+1
 \right) }}\\
&= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left( -{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{n}}{3}}+{
\frac {{2}^{n}}{3}} \right) {x}^{n}
\pmod{3}
\end{align}
and $-{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{n}}{3}}+{\frac {{2}^{n}}{3}} \pmod{3}$ is a periodic sequence with least period $6$: repeat in the pattern $$1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0.$$
This leads to $a(n) \equiv a(n+6) \pmod 3.$

Similarly, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\geq 1} a(n)x^n 
&\equiv  \sum_{1 \leq k \leq 4} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\binom{-\frac1x-1}{k-1}\binom{\frac1x-1}k}\\
&=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left( {\frac {13\,{2}^{n}}{30}}+{\frac {{4}^{n}
}{35}}+{\frac { \left( -2 \right) ^{n}}{10}}-{\frac { \left( -3
 \right) ^{n}}{35}}-{\frac {13\, \left( -1 \right) ^{n}}{30}}-{\frac {
{3}^{n}}{10}} \right) {x}^{n}
\pmod{5},
\end{align}

so $a(n) \pmod{5}$ is a periodic sequence with least period $20$: repeat in the pattern $$1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0.$$
This leads to $a(n) \equiv a(n+20) \pmod 5.$ **QED**

Moreover, we have the following

**Conjecture 7.** For any odd prime $p$,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{p(p-1)}a(n) \equiv 
  \begin{cases}
   p \pmod{p^2} &\mbox{if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ }\\
   0 \pmod{p^2} &\mbox{if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ }
   \end{cases}.
\end{equation}
It is true for $3 \leq p \leq 19$.

---

**ADDED** (2021-10-04)

**Conjecture 8.** For any  prime $p$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{p(p-1)}\left(\frac{a(n)}{p}\right)\equiv 0 \pmod p,$$
where $\left(\frac{\cdot}p\right)$ is the Legendre symbol.

It is true for $2 \leq p \leq 19$.

Comment: An alternative way of writing $C$ from conjecture 3 is $$C=\left[ \begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if } i + j \le n+1 \\ 2 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}\right]_{1\le j,k\le n}$$ Generalise to $$C_m=\left[ \begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if } i + j \le n+1 \\ m & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}\right]_{1\le j,k\le n}$$ and it seems that $\operatorname{per}(C_m) = E_n(m)$ where $E_n$ is the $n$th Eulerian polynomial.

Comment: Similarly, if $$B_m'=\left[ \begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if } i + j \le n \\ m & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}\right]_{1\le j,k\le n}$$ (so that $B$ is $C_2$ when $n$ is even and $B_2'$ when $n$ is odd), conjecture 2 generalises to $\operatorname{per}(B_m') = m E_n(m)$.

Comment: The generalised conjecture 3 is claimed on slide 8 of https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~jhaglund/talks/clemson.pdf and is apparently sufficiently folkloric not to need a reference.

Comment: @Peter Taylor
  Thank you for your answer. It looks like Conjecture 1 is more interesting.

Comment: Just for the record, $(a(n))_{n\geq 1}$ has the following generating function: $$\sum_{n\geq 1} a(n)\cdot x^n = \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\binom{-\frac1x-1}{k-1}\binom{\frac1x-1}k}.$$

Comment: @Max Alekseyev
 This is a beautiful formula. May I ask how it was obtained? Thanks!

Comment: @DeyiChen: "margin is too small" to explain it here, but the term for each $k$ essentially gives a g.f. for the number of such partitions with exactly $k$ parts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me outline an approach for computing permanents in these conjectures. For the sake of concreteness, I will prove Conjecture 1 for an odd $n$. The matrix here is the sum of the following two 0-1 matrices (using [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) notation):
$$A:=\big([2j-k \geq 1]\big)_{j,k=1}^n$$
and
$$B:=\big([2j-k \geq n+1]\big)_{j,k=1}^n$$
(notice that I intentionally redefine matrices $A$ and $B$). For example, for $n=5$, we have
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0\\ 1&1&1&0&0
\\ 1&1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&1&1&1
\\ 1&1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0
\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 1&1&0&0&0
\\ 1&1&1&1&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Our goal is to compute $\mathrm{per}(A+B)$ and show that it's equal to $a(n)$.

The crucial observation is that 0-1 matrices can be viewed as boards on which permanent enumerates [non-attacking rook placements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial). Furthermore, our matrices have the shape of [Ferrers boards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Ferrers_diagram), and the one for $B$ is a sub-board for that of $A$. From now on, I will not distinguish matrices $A$ and $B$ from the corresponding Ferrers boards.

I will use the notation and machinery from my [other answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/386804), which computes the number of non-attacking rook placements (i.e., the permanent) for the *difference* of a Ferrers board with its sub-board. In the current problem, we need to compute the number of placements of $n$ non-attacking rooks in $A$, where each placement comes with multiplicity $2^t$, where $t$ in the number of rooks in $B\subset A$.

Board $A$ has row lengths
$$a:=(1,3,5,\dots,n-2,\underbrace{n,n,\dots,n}_{(n+1)/2}),$$
while board $B$ has row lengths
$$b:=(\underbrace{0,0,\dots,0}_{(n+1)/2},2,4,\dots,n-1).$$

By inclusion-exclusion here, we have
$$\mathrm{per}(A+B) = \sum_{T\subseteq[n]} r_n(A_{\bar T}\| B_T),$$
where $\bar T := [n] \setminus T$ is the complement of $T$. The analog of formula $(\star)$ here gives the following expression:
$$\mathrm{per}(A+B) = \sum_{p\in\{0,1\}^n} \prod_{i=1}^n \big(p_i(a_i-\sum_{j=1}^{\tau_A(i)-1} \delta_j) + q_i(b_i-\sum_{j=1}^{\tau_B(i)-1} \delta_j)\big),$$
where $q_i:=1-p_i$ and
$$\sigma:=\big(\underbrace{0,0,\dots,0}_{(n+1)/2},1,2,\dots,n-1,\underbrace{n,n,\dots,n}_{(n+1)/2}\big),$$
$$\delta:=\big(q_1,q_2,\dots,q_{\frac{n+1}2},p_1,q_{\frac{n+1}2+1},p_2,q_{\frac{n+1}2+2},\dots,p_{\frac{n-1}2},q_n,p_{\frac{n+1}2},p_{\frac{n+1}2+1},\dots,p_n\big),$$
$$\tau_A:=\big( \frac{n+3}2,\frac{n+7}2, \dots, \frac{3n+1}2, \frac{3n+3}2,\frac{3n+5}2,\dots,2n\big),$$
$$\tau_B:=\big(1,2,\dots,\frac{n+1}2,\frac{n+1}2+2,\frac{n+1}2+4,\dots,\frac{3n-1}2\big).$$

Correspondingly, we have
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\tau_A(i)-1} \delta_j =
\begin{cases} 
i-1 + \sum_{j=i}^{\frac{n-1}2+i}q_j, & \text{if}\ i\leq\frac{n-1}2;\\
n - \sum_{j=i}^{n}p_j, & \text{if}\ i\geq\frac{n+1}2.
\end{cases}$$
and
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\tau_B(i)-1} \delta_j =
\begin{cases} 
\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} q_j & \text{if}\ i\leq\frac{n-1}2;\\
i-1 - \sum_{j=i-\frac{n-1}2}^{i-1}p_j, & \text{if}\ i\geq\frac{n+1}2.
\end{cases}$$

The formula then becomes
$$\mathrm{per}(A+B) = \sum_{p\in\{0,1\}^n} \prod_{i=1}^{(n-1)/2} \big(p_i(i - \sum_{j=i}^{\frac{n-1}2+i}q_j) - q_i \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} q_j)\big)
\prod_{i=(n+1)/2}^n \big(p_i\sum_{j=i}^{n}p_j + q_i(i-n + \sum_{j=i-\frac{n-1}2}^{i-1}p_j)\big).$$

We can see that if $\min\{i\,:\,q_i=1\}\leq\frac{n-1}2$, then the corresponding summand is zero. Hence, we can restrict summation to $(p_i,q_i)=(1,0)$ for all $i\leq\frac{n-1}2$, and further the same holds for $i=\frac{n+1}2$. Shifting indices $i\to \frac{n+1}2+i$, we get the formula:
\begin{split}
&\mathrm{per}(A+B) = \sum_{p\in\{0,1\}^{\frac{n-1}2}} (1 + \sum_{j=1}^{\frac{n-1}2} p_i) \prod_{i=1}^{(n-1)/2} \big(p_i\sum_{j=i}^{\frac{n-1}2} p_j + q_i (1+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} p_j)\big)(1+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} p_j) \\
&=\sum_{p\in\{0,1\}^{\frac{n-1}2}} 
\bigg( (1 + \sum_{j=1}^{\frac{n-1}2} p_i) \prod_{i=1\atop p_i=1}^{(n-1)/2} \sum_{j=i}^{\frac{n-1}2} p_j\bigg) \cdot
\bigg( \prod_{i=1\atop p_i=0}^{(n-1)/2} (1+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} p_j) \bigg) \cdot
\bigg( \prod_{i=1}^{(n-1)/2} (1+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} p_j) \bigg)
\end{split}

---

Now, let's show that this is exactly $a(n)$. More specifically, if we restrict summation to fixed $1 + \sum_{j=1}^{\frac{n-1}2} p_i =: k$, then the sum gives the number of ordered set partitions with $k$ parts.

Think of constructing a set partition by assigning elements $1,2,\dots,n$ in order to some part, and of $p_i$ as the indicator for $2i+1$ being a smallest element in its part (element $1$ has to be the smallest in its part, and this where "$1+$ in the formula comes from). Then

- $(1 + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\frac{n-1}2} p_i) \prod\limits_{i=1\atop p_i=1}^{(n-1)/2} \sum\limits_{j=i}^{\frac{n-1}2} p_j = k!$ accounts for the order of parts;
- $\prod\limits_{i=1\atop p_i=0}^{(n-1)/2} (1+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} p_j)$ accounts for assignments of $2i+1$ to one of $1+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} p_j$ parts, whose smallest elements are smaller than $2i+1$;
- $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{(n-1)/2} (1+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} p_j)$ accounts for assignments of $2i$ to one of $1+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} p_j$ parts (whose smallest elements are smaller than $2i$).

Hence, $\mathrm{per}(A+B) = a(n)$. QED

Answer (score 4):

Here is another proof of Conjecture 1, based on a combinatorial interpretation of entries in $A$. The same method works for proving Conjecture 3.

---

The key observation is that each permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ generates distinct odd-leading ordered set partitions, which are counted by a term $\prod_{j=1}^n A'_{j\tau_j}$ in the permanent of a matrix closely related to $A$.

Given a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$, we can construct odd-leading ordered set partitions by going from left to right through $\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \dots \sigma_n$ and inserting boundaries ("dividers") between partition blocks. If $\sigma_i$ is followed by $\sigma_{i+1}$, then the block to which $\sigma_{i}$ belongs may continue if $\sigma_{i}<\sigma_{i+1}$ (i.e. if including $\sigma_{i+1}$ does not break the ordering requirement). If $\sigma_{i+1}$ is odd and therefore may lead a block, then we may insert a divider after $\sigma_i$. If both conditions are true, each option (inserting or not inserting a divider) generates a different partition. If neither condition is true - if $\sigma_{i+1}$ is even and $\sigma_{i+1} < \sigma_{i}$ - then there are no legal partitions generated from this permutation.

For example, for $\sigma = 1234567$, we may optionally place dividers after $2$, $4$, and $6$ for a total of $2^3$ partitions. For $\sigma = 7512346$, we are forced to place dividers after $7$ and $5$ to preserve order within blocks but we may optionally place a divider after $2$, resulting in two partitions $7|5|12346$ and $7|5|12|346$. For $\sigma = 7521346$, there are no legal partitions: we cannot have a divider after $5$ because $2$ is even and may not lead a block, but we also cannot continue the block after $5$ because $2$ is less than $5$.

If $j$ is followed by $k$ in a permutation, then the number of options at that point (continue, insert divider, or neither) are counted by the $n\times n$ matrix $A'$ defined by $$A'_{jk}= \left [ k\text{ odd}\right ] + \left [j < k\right ],$$
using [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

For example for $n = 7$,
$$\left[ \begin {array}{ccccccc} 
1&1&2&1&2&1&2\\ 
1&0&2&1&2&1&2\\ 
1&0&1&1&2&1&2\\ 
1&0&1&0&2&1&2\\ 
1&0&1&0&1&1&2\\ 
1&0&1&0&1&0&2\\ 
1&0&1&0&1&0&1 \end {array}
 \right] .$$

By transposing $A'$ and rearranging the rows to put all even-indexed rows before the odd-indexed rows (so e.g. rows $1234567 \mapsto 2461357$), we recover $A$. The permanent is invariant under these operations, so ​$\text{per}(A') = \text{per}(A)$.

We now bijectively construct a permutation $\tau$ from $\sigma$, in order to interpret $A'_{j\tau_j}$ as the number of options for when $j$ is followed by $\tau_j$. We cannot use $A'_{\sigma_i \sigma_{i+1}}$ directly: $A'_{\sigma_n\sigma_1}$ does not reflect that the final block must terminate.

Given a permutation $\sigma$ in [one-line notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#One-line_notation), let $\tau$ be the unique permutation obtained by inserting parentheses into $\sigma$ to form a permutation in "reverse" [canonical cycle notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Canonical_cycle_notation) (list smallest element in each cycle first, sort cycles in decreasing order on the first element). For example, $\sigma=7512346$ maps to $(7)(5)(12346)$, or in one-line notation $\tau = 2346517$. By an analogous variant of [Foata's transition lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Foata%27s_transition_lemma), $\sigma \mapsto \tau$ is a bijection.

Note that:

- Any block in an ordered set partition defined from $\sigma$ is completely contained within a single cycle of $\tau$. (A cycle only terminates when the following element is less than the current one, which also means that a block would terminate.)
- For a number $\sigma_i$ not terminating a cycle, $\sigma_i$ is followed by $\tau_{\sigma_i}$.
- For a number $\sigma_i$ terminating a cycle $\sigma_{k}\sigma_{k+1}\dots\sigma_i$, we have that  $\tau_{\sigma_i}=\sigma_k$ and $A'_{\sigma_i \tau_{\sigma_i}} = \left [ \sigma_k \text{ odd} \right ]$, and indicates whether $\sigma_k$ may lead a partition block starting there.

Given the above, we may choose to either insert a block divider or continue a block after $\sigma_i$ precisely if $A'_{\sigma_i\tau_{\sigma_i}}=2$. We may not construct a partition if for any $i$, $A'_{\sigma_i\tau_{\sigma_i}} = 0$ (i.e. if a cycle is lead by an even number or if, within a cycle, an even number follows a larger number). The total number of odd-leading ordered set partitions generated from $\sigma$ is therefore $\prod_{i=1}^n A'_{\sigma_i\tau_{\sigma_i}} = \prod_{j=1}^n A'_{j\tau_j}$.

Each partition $P$ is defined by a unique permutation $\sigma$ (because the numbers occur in the same order), and hence each permanent term counts distinct partitions.
$a(n)$ can be partitioned into the sum:
$$a(n) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \#\left\{\text{partition }P : P \text{ defined by }\sigma\right\} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{j=1}^n A'_{j\tau_j} = \text{per}(A') = \text{per}(A),$$

which concludes the proof.

---

The proof of Conjecture 3 is similar. Here we are concerned with counting all ordered set partitions, instead of restricting to partitions with odd-leading blocks. We define a matrix $C'$ analogous to $A'$ but without the oddness condition by

$$(C')_{jk}= 1 + \left [j < k\right ],$$

and continue analogously.

Answer (score 3):

The proof of Conjecture 4 is given below

**Lemma 1** For any odd prime $p$,

$$\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}(x-i^2) \equiv x^{p-1}-2x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1 \pmod p$$
**Proof**
By Lagrange's Theorem  we have the relation
\begin{align}
y^{p-1}-1 \equiv \prod_{i=1}^{p-1}(y-i) 
          \equiv \prod_{i=1}^{p-1}(-y-i) \pmod p\\
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\left(y^{p-1}-1\right)^2 \equiv \prod_{i=1}^{p-1}(y^2-i^2) \pmod p       
\end{align}
Let $y^2=x$, we get Lemma 1.

**Lemma 2** For any odd $m$, we have the following identity
$$x^{m(m-1)/2}-1=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}kx^{(m-1)(m-k-1)/2}\right)\left(x^{m-1}-2x^{\frac{m-1}{2}}+1\right)+m(x^{\frac{m-1}{2}}-1).$$
**Proof** Let $q=x^{(m-1)/2}$ and just compare the coefficients of both sides of the equation.

**Proof of Conjecture 4 (Sam Zackrisson and Deyi Chen)**

Conjecture 4  holds for $p = 2$ obviously. Suppose $p$ is an odd prime number.

Let $a_k(n)$ = Number of ordered set partitions of $[n]$ with precisely $k$ blocks such that the smallest element of each block is odd.
It is not difficult to obtain
\begin{equation}
   a_k(n+2)=
   \begin{cases}
   k^2\left(a_k(n)+a_{k-1}(n)\right)&\mbox{if $n$ is even},\\
   k^2a_k(n)+k(k-1)a_{k-1}(n)&\mbox{if $n$ is odd},
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$a(n)=\sum_{k}a_k(n)$ and $a(n)\equiv \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}a_k(n) \pmod p$.
We have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1(n+2) \\ a_2(n+2) \\ \vdots\\ a_{p-1}(n+2) \end{bmatrix}
=A\begin{bmatrix}
a_1(n) \\ a_2(n) \\ \vdots\\ a_{p-1}(n) \end{bmatrix}
$$
where
$$
   A=
\begin {bmatrix}
     1^2  & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
     2^2 & 2^2& \cdots  & 0 & 0 \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
     0 & 0 & \cdots &  (p-1)^2 &(p-1)^2    
\end {bmatrix} \mbox{if $n$ is even}
$$
and
$$
   A=
\begin {bmatrix}
     1^2  & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
     1\cdot2 & 2^2& \cdots  & 0 & 0 \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
     0 & 0 & \cdots &  (p-2)(p-1) &(p-1)^2    
\end {bmatrix} \mbox{if $n$ is odd}.
$$
The eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ are $1^2,2^2,\cdots,(p-1)^2$, so
the  characteristic  polynomial  of  $A$ equals to
$$\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}(x-i^2).$$
By Hamilton-Cayley Theorem, we have
$$\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}(A-i^2I)=0,$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.
By lemma 1 we deduce
$$ A^{p-1}-2A^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+I \equiv \prod_{i=1}^{p-1}(A-i^2I)=0 \pmod p.$$
Combined with Lemma 2, we have
$$ A^{p(p-1)/2}-I \equiv p(A^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1)\equiv 0 \pmod p,$$
i.e.
$$ A^{p(p-1)/2} \equiv I \pmod p.$$
So we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1(n+p(p-1)) \\ a_2(n+p(p-1)) \\ \vdots\\ a_{p-1}(n+p(p-1)) \end{bmatrix}\equiv 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1(n) \\ a_2(n) \\ \vdots\\ a_{p-1}(n) \end{bmatrix} \pmod p
$$
which is more than enougth to prove
$$ a(n+p(p-1)) \equiv a(n) \pmod p$$
for any prime $p$. **QED**